# Best practice for marking hooks as not to be reused in multiple places

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

It seems a lot of my custom React Hooks don't work well, or seem to cause a big performance overhead if they are reused in multiple places. For example:

- A hook that is only called in the context provider and sets up some context state/setters for the rest of the app to use
- A hook that should only be called in a root component of a Route to setup some default state for the page
- A hook that checks if a resource is cached and if not, retrieves it from the backend

Is there any way to ensure that a hook is only referenced once in a stack? Eg. I would like to trigger a warning or error when I call this hook in multiple components in the same cycle.

Alternatively, is there a pattern that I should use that simply prevents it being a problem to reuse such hooks?

Example of hook that should not be reused (third example). If I would use this hook in multiple places, I would most likely end up making unnecessary API calls.

```
export function useFetchIfNotCached({id}) {

  const {apiResources} = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!apiResources[id]) {
      fetchApiResource(id); // sets result into apiResources
    }
  }, [apiResources]);

  return apiResources[id];

}
```

Example of what I want to prevent (please don't point out that this is a contrived example, I know, it's just to illustrate the problem):

```
export function Parent({id}) {
   const resource = useFetchIfNotCached({id});

   return <Child id={id}>{resource.Name}</Child>

}

export function Child({id}) {
   const resource = useFetchIfNotCached({id}); // <--- should not be allowed

   return <div>Child: {resource.Name}</div>

}
```

Comment: do you have some code? did you try to write something?

Answer (score 3):

You need to transform your custom hooks into singleton stores, and subscribe to them directly from any component.

See [`reusable` library](https://github.com/reusablejs/reusable) implementation.

```
const Comp1 = () => {
  const something = useCounter(); // is a singleton
}

const Comp2 = () => {
  const something = useCounter(); // same something, no reset
}
```

To ensure that a hook called only once, you only need to add a state for it.

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [isCalled, setIsCalled] = useState(false);

  // Your hook logic
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  const onSetState = (value) => {
    setIsCalled(true);
    setState(value);
  };
  return { state, setState: onSetState, isCalled };
};
```

Edit:

If you introduce a global variable in your custom hook you will get the expected result. Thats because global variables are not tied to component's lifecycle

```
let isCalledOnce = false;

const useCustomHook = () => {
  // Your hook logic
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  const onSetState = (value) => {
    if (!isCalledOnce) {
      isCalledOnce = true;
      setState(false);
    }
  };
  return { state, setState: onSetState, isCalled };
};
```

Comment: I think I didn't clearly explained what I meant. I don't mean the hook should only be called once. It should be called on every render. What I want to ensure that it is only included in one place in the cycle. It should still run on each render.

Comment: Still don't understand what "What I want to ensure that it is only included in one place in the cycle" means, please add more context with code to your question

Comment: Added some code to the question to show what I want to avoid.

Comment: Added another example @wvdz

Comment: Okay, but the problem is I can't distinguish between the parent and the child calling it. Eg. I still want a useEffect to trigger if its dependencies change, just not when it happens in a child component that uses the hook.

Comment: So pass a parameter to your hook... `isParent`

Comment: It seems I'm still not clear on what I want to achieve. It's not about how do I do this, it's about how do I prevent others from using the hook in a wrong way. My question is about best practices.

Comment: Best practices are opinionated (no no in StackOverflow), if you show a **specific** example with **reproducible** example, we can talk about **the most efficient way** to solve it, but your question is too vague, good luck.

Comment: Where does it say you can't ask about best practices on SO? Btw, it should be pretty clear from the question title I'm looking for a best practice...